# Cant upload larger than 100MB

Tags: uploads

I am using DO Droplet 2gb RAM Shared CPU running apache. I cant upload files larger than 100MB in the Media Uploader but I can upload LOWER than 100mb. I already tried modifying php.ini and other stuffs like htaccess and wp-config.

```
@ini_set( 'upload_max_filesize' , '512M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '512M');
@ini_set( 'memory_limit', '512M' );
@ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '300' );
@ini_set( 'max_input_time', '300' );
```

php.ini is also modified like the above. Media uploader on backend shows I can upload 512M but its just stuck in 1% or 0%. Tried uploading larger than 512M it shows an error.

I tried also reinstalling BOOT IMAGE like Wordpress on Ubuntu and OpenLiteSpeed Wordpress and Suchs but still not working with the changed PHP.INI values and same.

I was thinking that this is a wordpress problem as I tried other PHP Scripts and it uploads larger than 100M.

Help is appreciated. Thank you guys!

Comment: Have you restarted the PHP service after changing your settings ?

Comment: Yes. already restarted many times. Tried changing apache nginx and openlitespeed, same problem

Comment: You can check if your server settings are active under https://www.example.com/wp-admin/site-health.php?tab=debug maybe they are never set.